# how to use an existing database in prediction.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, prediction

I have an existing project that uses nodejs and mongoDB (through mongoose) as the backend, and now I want to integrate all the awesomeness of prediction.io to it without touching the existing data structure, but with the [current](https://github.com/ShaunBaker/PredictionIO-Node-SDK) [node.js](https://github.com/kostyantyn/PredictionIO-NodeJS-Client) SDKs I don't see how it is possible.
basically, what I want to do is use mongoose to directly interact with my database, and use the api to register actions and retrieve predictions..
so my questions here are:
* how to make prediction.io use an existing database?
* what should be the changes to make to the existing documents so that it works?

Comment: The PredictionIO documentation has information on [Using Existing Infrastructure](http://docs.prediction.io/current/deployment/distributed.html#using-existing-infrastructure). I'm not sure what further needs to be done in your client configuration, but you might want to search/post in the [`predictionio-user` community forum](http://groups.google.com/group/predictionio-user).

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the appropriate documentation, I think I won't use an SDK for this, but now, should I change the nae of my collections to match those of prediction.io (users+items)

Comment: *change the `name` of my collections

Comment: @Stennie I forgot to mention you in my previous comments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it isn't possible to use an existing database for the time being,
as it has been stated in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/DaVD31b8m6M), the next version will make this possible.

Comment: i have a mysql database. is this possible to integrate my datebase into prediction io. please clarify me...